# Shared C3P0 JNDI DataSource gets closed during Jetty's servlet undeployment, no longer accessible to other servlets

Tags: spring, servlets, jetty, jndi, c3p0

Several servlets run inside my Jetty container. **All** these servlets use **one** `DataSource` exposed via JNDI. This `DataSource` is a C3P0 `ComboPooledDataSource`.

At the moment I **undeploy** any of those servlets, somehow the `ComboPooledDataSource` gets "closed". From this moment on, both the already-deployed servlets and any additionally deployed servlets can no longer access the `DataSource`. Therefore, all servlets that need that `DataSource` stop working at the next access to said `DataSource`.

Here is a commented stacktrace:

```
## Undeploying a servlet named "c.war" by issuing "rm -f ${jetty.base}/webapps/c.war"
## Thread "Scanner-0" recognizes that something has changed in the webapps directory,
## therefore "Scanner-0" shuts down components inside the c.war servlet:

2013-12-23 17:19:11,977 container [Scanner-0] INFO  c - Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
2013-12-23 17:19:11,977 container [Scanner-0] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Mon Dec 23 17:18:01 CET 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2013-12-23 17:19:11,977 container [Scanner-0] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6def78d2: defining beans []; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@477ed07f
2013-12-23 17:19:11,980 container [Scanner-0] INFO  c - Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2013-12-23 17:19:11,980 container [Scanner-0] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Dec 23 17:17:37 CET 2013]; root of context hierarchy
2013-12-23 17:19:11,998 container [Scanner-0] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
2013-12-23 17:19:12,003 container [Scanner-0] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler my_scheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
2013-12-23 17:19:12,006 container [Scanner-0] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@477ed07f: defining beans [long, list, of, my, spring, beans, shortened, for, brevity]; root of factory hierarchy
2013-12-23 17:19:12,007 container [Scanner-0] INFO  org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess - Removing TilesContext for context: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringTilesApplicationContextFactory$SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext
2013-12-23 17:19:12,014 container [Scanner-0] INFO  o.s.s.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean - Shutting down Quartz Scheduler
2013-12-23 17:19:12,014 container [Scanner-0] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler my_scheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
2013-12-23 17:19:12,014 container [Scanner-0] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler my_scheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
2013-12-23 17:19:12,056 container [Scanner-0] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler my_scheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
2013-12-23 17:19:12,155 container [Scanner-0] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@676e4e1c{/c,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-c.war-_c-any-8486076679973394405.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/c.war}

## Thread "Scanner-0" has finished undeploying c.war

## A few seconds later, thread "my_scheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" from unrelated 
## servlet "b.war" tries to do stuff with the JNDI-obtained DataSource, but fails:

2013-12-23 17:19:19,688 container [my_scheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] ERROR org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger - An error occurred while scanning for the next triggers to fire.
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'springNonTxDataSource.my_scheduler': java.sql.SQLException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> ai8gp08z8xy71x5vsabw|11f7562b, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> ai8gp08z8xy71x5vsabw|11f7562b, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 28000, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 40, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 20, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ] has been closed() -- you can no longer use it.
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreCMT.java:168) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3784) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTriggers(JobStoreSupport.java:2756) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:272) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> ai8gp08z8xy71x5vsabw|11f7562b, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> ai8gp08z8xy71x5vsabw|11f7562b, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 28000, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 40, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 20, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ] has been closed() -- you can no longer use it.
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.assertCpds(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:507) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre6.jar:0.9.5-pre6]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getPoolManager(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:519) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre6.jar:0.9.5-pre6]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre6.jar:0.9.5-pre6]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore$2.getConnection(LocalDataSourceJobStore.java:129) ~[spring-context-support-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.getConnection(DBConnectionManager.java:108) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreCMT.java:165) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

So the relevant message here is:

```
An error occurred while scanning for the next triggers to fire.
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException:
Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'springNonTxDataSource.my_scheduler':
java.sql.SQLException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [...] has been closed() -- you can no longer use it.
```

The above shows a problem with the Quartz Scheduler, which can no longer access the database. The same problem happens e.g. when interacting with database-backed repositories.

I use:

- Jetty `9.1.0.v20131115`
- C3P0 `0.9.1.1` ... (I also tried `0.9.5-pre6`, same symptoms)
- MYSQL J/Connector `5.1.27`

The JNDI `DataSource` is set up like this in my Jetty XML configuration:

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <New id="jdbc-mydb" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/mydb</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <Set name="DriverClass">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Set>
        <Set name="JdbcUrl">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</Set>
        <Set name="User">user</Set>
        <Set name="Password">pass</Set>
        <Set name="MaxPoolSize">40</Set>
        <Set name="MinPoolSize">20</Set>
        <Set name="MaxIdleTime">28000</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>
</Configure>
```

When instead of C3P0 I use a plain MySQL driver, then my servlets deploy, undeploy, and redeploy without problems:

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <New id="jdbc-mydb" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/mydb</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
        <Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</Set>
        <Set name="User">user</Set>
        <Set name="Password">pass</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>
</Configure>
```

How can undeploy a servlet without "closing" the C3P0 `DataSource`?

Comment: Do you have any ServletContextListener closing the datasource in its contextDestroyed() method?

Comment: jndi looks server scoped so this smells like a bug, open an issue at bugs.eclipse.org under RT/Jetty [edit] or a c3p0 bug actually...open an issue and we can validate it is not jetty at least

Comment: @DavidLevesque and jessemcconnell: you two made me investigate into the right direction (see my answer). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

For my case, the symptoms turned out to be caused by neither C3P0 nor Jetty: The JNDI-shared C3P0 `DataSource` was closed by **Spring** at the servlet's *Spring container shutdown time* (i.e. when issuing `rm -f ${jetty.base}/webapps/c.war`).

**Explanation**
My servlets are Spring-based. I exploit Spring's *JavaConfig*. In my Spring-based servlets, I use `@Configuration` classes such as this one:

```
@Configuration
public class MainConfig {
    //...
    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource myds = null;
        JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
        try {
            myds = (DataSource) jndi.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            logger.error("NamingException for java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb", e);
        }
        return myds;
    }
}
```

Spring's `@Bean` has the following relevant semantics:

> As a convenience to the user, the container will attempt to infer a destroy method against object returned from the `@Bean` method. [...] This 'destroy method inference' is currently limited to detecting only public, no-arg methods named **`close`**. The method may be declared at any level of the inheritance hierarchy, and will be detected regardless of the return type of the `@Bean` method, i.e. detection occurs reflectively against the bean instance itself at creation time.
>
> To disable destroy method inference for a particular `@Bean`, specify an empty string as the value, e.g. `@Bean(destroyMethod="")`.

It turns out that `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource` **does have** a `close()` method (in its supertype `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource`).

So when undeployment of my servlet takes place, at *Spring container shutdown time*, Spring will call `ComboPooledDataSource.close()`. IMHO, semantically, in this particular situation, Spring is wrong to call this method.

The solution to my cause is to annotate my `DataSource` bean with `@Bean(destroyMethod="")`:

```
@Configuration
public class MainConfig {
    //...
    @Bean(destroyMethod="")
    DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource myds = null;
        JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
        try {
            myds = (DataSource) jndi.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            logger.error("NamingException for java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb", e);
        }
        return myds;
    }
}
```

Now all my servlets get gracefully undeployed, redployed, and deployed.